# How to Setup Private Proxy with Selenium?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, proxy

I've been trying for days to setup a private proxy (with authentication) in Selenium using Firefox. However, no matter what I do I'v been unsuccessful.

Currently, I have tried the following two approaches and in both cases Firefox launches normally **without any proxy**.

```
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyHost + proxyPort);
        proxy.setSocksUsername(proxyUsername); 
        proxy.setSocksPassword(proxyPass);
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy); 



        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);

        driver.get("http://google.com");
```

I have also tried the following:

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", proxyHost);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", proxyPort);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "user:pass@1.1.1.1");
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", proxyPort);

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

    driver.get("http://google.com");
```

How can I setup http private proxies (with user name and password in Selenium with Firefox)?

I am using Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const proxy = require('selenium-webdriver/proxy');
(async function example(){
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').setProxy(proxy.manual({
    http: 'zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225',
    https: 'zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225'
  })).build()
  try {
    await driver.get('http://lumtest.com/myip.json');
    driver.switchTo().alert()
      .sendKeys('lum-customer-USERNAME-zone-YOURZONE'+Key.TAB+'PASSWORD');
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
  } finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```

Here is [my sample code](https://www.privateproxyreviews.com/selenium-proxy/) when I use Luminati proxy for Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [browsermob proxy](http://bmp.lightbody.net/). 
Here you go for [example](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Find solution:

```
proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': PROXY_HOST,
    'socksUsername': 'name',
    'socksPassword': 'pass'
    })

driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
```