# Selenium - Instantiate with Private Proxy

Tags: java, selenium, proxy

I've been trying for weeks to figure out how to launch Selenium with a private proxy to no avail. I need to achieve this functionality without the need to download any additional JAR files.

Hence, the following response on SO [How to Setup Private Proxy with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674994/how-to-setup-private-proxy-with-selenium) will not suffice for my purpose.

Is there any way to achieve this using native Java code?

Again, to be clear, I have a proxy with a IP + Port + Username + Password and I need to pass this to Firefox profile somehow so Selenium sends traffic through proxy. How can it be done?

I've looked through dozens of queries/answers on SO but to my amazement I found no easy / elegant way to accomplish this..

Comment: And what have you achieved so far? Is there some code we could look at and mention where to improve it?

Comment: I tried like a dozen different strategies but all of them failed.. I don't think there's what to improve because it seems like they are just the incorrect path (even though many of them have been suggested here on SO) - I tested them and they simply didn't work.. Shall I copy and paste the various methods I tried using? I don't think it will help but if you wish I can do it..